# how to group items returned in array in PHP

Tags: php

I need to list all PDF files in a directory and link to them. I do it like this:

```
//get the list and sort it
<?php
    $dirpath = "Files/PDFs/";
    $files = array();
    $files = glob($dirpath . "*");
    // sort files by last modified date
    usort($files, function($x, $y) {
        return filemtime($x) < filemtime($y);
    }); 
?>
//display them like this
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach($files as $item){
            echo "<li><a href='$item'>" . basename($item) . " Updated On " . @date('F d, Y, H:i:s', filemtime($item)) . "</a></li>";
    } ?>
</ul>
```

This gives me something like this:

```
<li><a href="/pat/to/pdf">File.pdf Updated On August 13, 2021, 16:43:49</a></li>
```

Which is part of what I need.

I would like to add a class to each item "left, mid, right" so I can assign them to a css grid column. So if there were 10 items returned:

```
Left            Mid            Right
1               2               3
4               5               6
7               8               9
10
```

Is there a better way to get these to lay out in a grid column or table?

Comment: Use an array `$classes=['left', 'mid', 'right']`. Then increment the array index each time through the loop, wrapping around when it reaches 3.

Comment: Have a look at `array_chunk`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk

Comment: I get the concept, but don't know how to do that. $classes=['left', 'mid', 'right']; classes ++

Comment: don't use a table, you mention grid, so take bootstrap for example it would be `<div class="col-4">`, they would align to 3 cols wide.. you can also use modulo https://3v4l.org/clYLN but its not needed if you use flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the direct answer to what you want:

```php
<?php
foreach($files as $index => $item){
     echo "<li class='". ($index % 3 == 0 ? "left-class" : ($index % 3 == 1 ? "middle-class" : "right-class")) ."'>
          <a href='$item'>" . basename($item) . " Updated On " . @date('F d, Y, H:i:s', filemtime($item)) . "</a>
     </li>";
} 
?>
```

But there is better way of doing that using flex boxes or grid system. Take a look at [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Then you could do something like this:

```php
<div class="row">
    <?php
        foreach($files as $item){
            echo "<div class='col-4'><a href='$item'>" . basename($item) . " Updated On " . @date('F d, Y, H:i:s', filemtime($item)) . "</a></div>";
    } ?>
</div >
```

Comment: Thats what I would have ended up doing, or used named grid columns and applied a named grid column to each class. Wanted to learn how to loop through and add the class - similar to the first answer you provided. However that adds 'middle-class' to each item.

Comment: I've edited the answer adding ```(``` and ```)``` so that it may give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about assigning them to a column - let CSS do the work for you.

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr);
}



/* styles below here are just to make it look pretty */
.grid{
  gap:1rem;
}
.cell{
  background:lightblue;
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
  <div class="cell">File</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to use named grid columns and assign a grid column to each class name

Comment: That's an option, but it's more work than needed to solve the stated problem.

Comment: "That's an option, but it's more work than needed to solve the stated problem" 100% correct! Should have just stuck to what I know - CSS. Easy and don't need to iterate through the array - which Im struggling to do. Good to have choices! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk):

```php
<?php

$arr = range(1, 10);

foreach (array_chunk($arr, 3) as $row) {
  echo implode("\t", $row) . "\n";
}

// 1    2    3
// 4    5    6
// 7    8    9
// 10
```